# New alert keeps showing up: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001

Tags: server, dns, systemd-resolved

I just installed a new Ubuntu Server 18.04. I set my hostname `hostnamectl set-hostname ****.openbayou.biz` and I set `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
[ip address] ****.openbayou.biz hostname
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
[ip6 address] *****.openbayou.biz hostname
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I also installed OSSEC to monitor for new files, errors and changes to my server and I'm now getting these alerts:

```
Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018- 
0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.`
```

It's now repeating itself:

```
systemd-resolved[3195]: message repeated 4 times: [ Server returned error 
NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction 
with reduced feature level UDP.]
```

I've looked online for a solution and nobody is reporting this issue.

Comment: Are you behind a captive portal?

Comment: No, this is a Linode 4GB server

Comment: If you comment out the two lines you added, does it make a difference? I don't think the errors are about your /etc/hosts. They are happening because of the infrastructure the server is behind is likely doing something wrong.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/8608 seems to be the issue you're having, and was the first search result for "DVE-2018-0001." I don't think you're going to get a satisfactory answer until the upstream issue is fixed and released.

Comment: I got this error when my country blocked torrents

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This warning is logged by systemd-resolved, whenever a name can not be resolved by the DNS system (e.g. nslookup [www.kjfoiqaefah34876asdf.com](http://www.kjfoiqaefah34876asdf.com)). This can be tolerated and is no reason to be alarmed.
This is no error and nothing needs to be fixed.

Redirecting `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` is wrong, because this way `systemd-resolved` is skipped and the application with the faulty DNS request talks directly to the name server and not to the `systemd-resolved` stub anymore. This way `systemd-resolved` does not notice the NXDOMAIN events any more and therefore cannot log it any more.

The NXDOMAIN events are caused by packages, which try to access non-existing servers during system startup.

Comment: Is there any way to discover what the unresolved names are?

Comment: @OrangeDog `tcpdump -vv port 53 | grep NXDomain`

Comment: So there is no existing log of the application or domain that caused the log message?

Comment: `tcpdump` is not very convenient at boot time...

Comment: Unless you actually have a problem this error is harmless.  It means you searched for a domain name (like a web site name) that didn't exist.  It is telling you that it is using a workaround to make sure that the domain really doesn't exit.

More of these errors need to be tagged "This error is harmless" meaning it's only for info in case you are actually looking at something that went wrong. 

The other option is to just tag it "INFO:"

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with bypassing systemd-resolved by symlinking `/etc/resolv.conf`. Nobody asked for `systemd-resolved` to be created in the first place, let alone made nearly impossible to disable, like some piece of malware. DNS works just fine without it.

Answer (score 55):

**IMPORTANT: The solution posted here hides the problematic message by bypassing an important part of your system (the DNS resolver daemon). It may cause DNS malfunction in the future ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential#comment2081707_1091556)). For a proper way to handle the error message please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential#1102401).**

---

```
Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018- 
0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

*The same error happened to my desktop machine, I don't know if it applies to server too.*

It seems that my system had the old config in the place, resulting in a conflict between two services: `resolvconf` and `systemd-resolved`.

The symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` pointed to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Changing it to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` which is managed by systemd, fixed it for me.

Read more [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371249&p=13686337#post13686337)

Hope that helped.

Comment: Mine is pointing to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` on an Ubuntu 18.10 instance.

Comment: Forgot to mention my system. Latest KDE Neon, (Ubuntu based), 18.04.1, 4.15.0-39-generic.

Comment: @datashaman It was the same case for me but changing the symlink to point `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` from `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` fixed the issue for me. I no longer see that error.

Comment: Same worked for me. I'm on 18.10, but migrated from 18.04. Changing the `/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` did the trick.

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis any chance you could edit the answer with the command required to change the symlink?

Comment: @Dennis generally, to change the target of a symlink, you use `ln -fs /path/to/file2 /path/to/symlink`. In my case it was `ln -fs /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: This error can be returned if systemd-resolved has no forwarders set.

Comment: This is the wrong thing to do. This does not fix anything but actually breaks how the resolver is supposed to work. The error message goes away because the systemd resolver gets bypassed. See the answer of Hermann Klein below.

Comment: I tested this. As a practical drawback, this broke DNS resolution when using a VPN.

Comment: Mine was pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf on an Ubuntu 20.04. relinked to Mine is pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf restart and works

Comment: Changing an important system-level file like this is a bad idea and will only cause pain further down the line.

Answer (score 15):

[I asked on the OSSEC GitHub about this error](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/issues/1479) and they recommended writing a rule to ignore NXDOMAIN errors. Add to `/var/ossec/rules/local_rules.xml`

```
<rule id="234567" level="0">
 <program_name>systemd-resolved</program_name>
 <match>Server returned error NXDOMAIN</match>
 <description>Usless systemd-resolvd log message</description>
</rule>
```

Comment: do you mind adding the link to the recommendation in your answer? It would be useful for others having the same issue. thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/issues/1479

Comment: not work in ubunto 18.04

Comment: does not work in ubuntu 20.04 either

Comment: Note for readers who want to say that this answer does not work: The question was about a message also caught in OSSEC, a software that is not installed by default in Ubuntu. This answer says, that one may ignore the message with a rule in OSSEC. If you look at journalctl or other logs the message will still be there.

Answer (score 14):

### Problem

Although there might be other circumstances where this error will occur, I can definitely say that I've seen it puked in the output of:

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved
```

...when `systemd-resolved` is not configured.

And an ***Azure*** Ubuntu 18.04 VM does not have `systemd-resolved` configured out-of-the-box (as of today, 20191008).

### Solution:

Configure `systemd-resolved`.

### Mini `systemd-resolved` Config HowTo:

**NOTE**: Following instructions were prepared using ***Ubuntu 18.04***

Edit `hosts` directive in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` by prepending `resolve` which sets systemd-resolved as first source of DNS resolution that will be consulted:

```
hosts:          resolve files dns
```

Edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. Some suggested settings:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=yes
```

Restart `systemd-resolved`:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

When you next check `systemd-resolved`'s status, the error should now be cleared:

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved
```

And DNS resolution should now behave in the expected way.

Comment: +1, IMHO good answer. Instead of suppressing/ignoring seems to address the root cause for machines where systemd-resolved is not configured. Thank you.

Comment: At least for my system, I now have more detail on the root cause.. (it might help others).
As per man page for systemd-resolved (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html) read the section starting with "The DNS servers contacted are determined from ... ...". Because I was not using DHCP provided DNS (and all other DNS resolution options listed in the man page also were not available), there was no other way for a name to get resolved.
Setting the DNS value in [Resolve] section allows the service to use that for resolution.

Answer (score 12):

I noticed the same thing on an Ubuntu 18.04 server which was recently updated to 18.04.1.

It would appear that systemd-resolve logs that message whenever it gets any NXDOMAIN response. In my case I have postfix running. So I get a lot of NXDOMAINS when random servers connect that don't have PTR record set.

You can test it with

```
systemd-resolve securelogin.example.com
```

Then you should see the log message appear.

With this in mind it would appear to be a relatively innocuous error and you can ignore it.

Comment: Added PTR record and haven't gotten a notice (so far). Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Still getting them. Think next stage is to get OSSEC to ignore them. Would it be something related to Cloudflare as it's going through their systems and not being bypassed? Also, I see that OSSEC has an update (on 2.9.4, update to 3.0.0). Will update and see what happens.

Comment: It's just part of how systemd works. If systemd-resolve tries to resolve a domain that doesn't resolve it logs that message.

Comment: Ugh... what's good the error message when it doesn't contain information about which process tried to request the domain nor the domain name that was about to be resolved?

Answer (score 9):

My understanding after having read the previous answers and other web pages such as [Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-resolved error NXDOMAIN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain) is that this is more a warning than an error and there is nothing I can do on my side about it.

Therefore, I agree with those who say that we should not try to do something on our side so that these messages are not produced anymore.  If we succeed, it is likely that we have altered the normal way the system resolve DNS requests.

However, since I have thousands of them (I am also in a desktop - it's not a server), I don't want them in my syslog file. Therefore, following https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html and [Number pair prefix to config files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560371/number-pair-prefix-to-config-files), I added a file named `10-resolv.conf` with a single line `:msg, contains, "Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP" ~` in the directory `/etc/rsyslog.d`  .

The name `10-resolv.conf` is not important, but it must precede all other file names in the directory in alphabetic order. The command `:msg, contains, <message-part> ~` says that all messages that contains  <message-part> must be ignored: the tilde `~` in the command says to drop the message.

Note added: Since I wrote this answer, I installed some packages (for other reasons) and the error  message is not produced anymore as checked with `journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f`.  One installed package that might explain the disappearance of this message is libnss-resolve.

Comment: I still see the message after installing libnss-resolve. Still the best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

*NXDOMAIN* error message means that a domain does not exist.

Some ISPs started DNS hijacking or DNS redirection for NXDOMAIN error messages.
It is the practice of redirecting the resolution of Domain Name System (DNS) names to other DNS servers or web servers.

Commonly used for displaying advertisements or collecting statistics.

This practice violates the RFC standard for DNS (NXDOMAIN) responses.

Phishing: Cross-site scripting attacks can occur due to malicious hijacking.

Censorship: DNS service providers to block access to selected domains.

Shown up here: https://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/nxdomain-non-existent-domain-2/

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it doesn't link to 127.0.0.53 anymore, but I had no issues with it since re-linking.

I think there is a bug report out on this one. Anyway, it worked very well after re-linking.

Steps:

```
# systemctl status systemd-resolved

# unlink /etc/resolv.conf

# ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

# systemctl restart systemd-resolved

# systemctl status systemd-resolved
```

Comment: Never thought I had to write the following on this forum, but apparently "yes": The "#" is the root's prompt. As a normal user, you would need "sudo" on all non-"status" commands.

Comment: Could you please add some more explanation about why Herrman Klein is wrong here? As somebody with little previous knowledge on this topic, right now there are just three disagreeing answers, two with many votes and one which is newer. How or Why is Panagiotis not bypassing systemd. Why especially not if it was linked to `stub-resolv.conf` ?

Comment: It is bypassing systemd, because the requests are not sent anymore to 127.0.0.53, which is the systemd resolver. (Notice the difference between the `nameserver` lines.)

Comment: @Jocelyn: This I haven't checked. I amend my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the message, and by the way I was also able to finally connect to my samba server, by changing the server name to 
**`server.domain`** instead of only **`server`**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Google Cloud dislikes CloudFlare DNS. After running the following command from *bain* above

```
sudo tcpdump -vv port 53 | grep NXDomain
```

When I open my domain in a browser I get:

> dns.google.domain >
>   ....: [udp sum
>   ok] .... NXDomain q: PTR? ... ns:
>   .... SOA ....cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. ....

Might be the case with other VPS-CDN providers as well.

**Moving DNS to your VPS/Cloud provider can help.**

Answer (score -1):

This appears related to EDNS.  The difference between using `stub-resolv.conf` and `resolv.conf` is `options edns0`.

> Extension mechanisms for DNS (EDNS) is a specification for expanding the size of several parameters of the Domain Name System (DNS) protocol which had size restrictions that the Internet engineering community deemed too limited for increasing functionality of the protocol.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_mechanisms_for_DNS

More details under this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1766969

It sounds like, you can simply turn off that "option".

Comment: edns0 is needed by some client applications, for exemple for ensuring the response is validated by DNSSEC. It was added to systemd for this reason in this commit: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/93158c77bc69fde7cf5cff733617631c1e566fe8