# Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP

Tags: networking

There are many other questions are out there which already been answered regarding this topic but nothing was helpful to me.

```
systemd-resolved[713]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP
```

I am in Ubuntu `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64)`.

Most answers over internet says its not such a problem or an error, and resolving this `resolv.conf` or creating a symlink of the file and point to other `resolv.conf`.

The issue which is happening to my server is, when this error shows up in `syslog` about `NXDOMAIN`, the Phoenix/Elixir application running on this server stopped working, and all HTTP request to other ips and ports, start giving nxdomain errors as well.

I tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain/1115919#1115919

But totally clear the `resolv.conf` file and everything stops working.

Any help would be appreciable, The issue I am having is when this issue happens, All HTTP requests which are going out from the server stop working and also giving `nxdomain` error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and would be better suited for https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: No one answered here thats why i moved it there.