# "Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8" on new ubuntu installation on virtualbox over windows10

Tags: 18.04, dns, systemd-resolved

I am getting a lot of these messages on /var/log/syslog on my new installation of ubuntu 18.04 on a virtualbox over a windows 10 host. I was getting them on my previous installation of ubuntu on the same machine and tried all sort of solutions I found on the internet (like replacing resolved with bind9) without any luck, i.e. bind9 had issues resolving hosts. This makes surfing and any other software using the internet slow.

Note the issue occurs with 8.8.8.8 as well as an internal dns server on 10.255.255.0.

I am using the latest virtual box to run my latest ubuntu 18.04. Any work arounds for this? So far I tried:

- replacing systemd-resolved with bind9 (bind9 had issues resolving, and dns resolution was slow)
- removing the /etc/resolved.conf symbolic link and hardcoding values into that file
- setting the dns resolution to use 8.8.8.8 (same issue)

  ```
  Sep 20 11:23:21 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:23:26 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:23:30 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:23:35 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:23:40 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:23:40 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:23:48 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
  Sep 20 11:23:51 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:23:55 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:24:02 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:24:05 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:24:05 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:24:15 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: message repeated 2 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
  Sep 20 11:24:21 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 10.255.255.0.
  Sep 20 11:24:25 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
  Sep 20 11:24:56 kkpc systemd-resolved[553]: message repeated 6 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
  ```

Comment: See [askUbuntu_Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain/1115894)

Comment: Thanks @TonyB, this actually sorted it out: sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf