# Server returned error NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am currently installing Ubuntu and I'm using the web-browser the Ubuntu installer has (luckily).

I am stuck with the error "`ubuntu systemd-resolved[2309]: Server returned error XDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.`" Please help, I've been stuck here for I think about **2 hours**. (I just got Ubuntu so I don't have any clue what to do...)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is the client?

Comment: We need more information about your actual issue. What you have provided is not that unusual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-resolved error NXDOMAIN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain)

Answer (score 0):

This is a previously discovered issue when using ubuntu with EDNS0 requests.. My understanding is that its no an error in ubuntu its a problem with the downstream server rejecting the valid request being sent to it.

The issue/reasons and answer is discussed in great detail here:-

[Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-resolved error NXDOMAIN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain)