# Ubuntu 20.04 "Temporary failure in name resolution" - recently reinstalled

Tags: networking, dns, 20.04, resolv.conf

I rent a vps from contabo for about half a year now, it worked fine until now, because it started producing "Temporary failure in name resolution" errors. I read that this is a DNS error, I tried `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 1.1.1.1` but the problems is still here.

Also yesterday I completely reinstalled the vps but it didn't work.

### `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search invalid
```

### `resolvectl` status:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 213.136.95.11
         DNS Servers: 213.136.95.10
                      213.136.95.11
          DNS Domain: invalid
```

### `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`:

```
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-21 21:45:08 CEST; 1 day 14h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 460 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9487)
     Memory: 7.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─460 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

May 23 11:59:44 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:00:18 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:00:20 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:00:31 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:00:48 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:01:05 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:01:15 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:01:29 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:01:55 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 23 12:02:21 vmi329703.contaboserver.net systemd-resolved[460]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

I have a discord bot and usually the problem is came up there.

Comment: possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable ipv6 for the current lifecycle

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

and if everything is working fine then disable ipv6 permanently (as a temporary workaround)

```
~$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-disable.conf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```