# SSTP VPN automaticly turns off

Tags: vpn

I try to run SSTP VPN on Ubuntu 20.04. It first connects to the VPN server. To do so I must enable CHAP and PAP authentication methods. However, after some minutes it turns off (I can see via GUI), and when I check the options, the CHAP and PAP are disabled.

This is the syslog which could be related to the problem:

```
Jun 12 22:32:30 app systemd-resolved[917]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 12 22:32:30 app systemd-resolved[917]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

I don't know what causes this problem. Could you guide me what's happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New alert keeps showing up: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential).  Are you sure your ISP is not blocking you?

Comment: @Nmath no, I even don't know if the error is related to the vpn... moreover, the answers on the question say that is not a serious problem and can be ignored