# Ubuntu 20.04.1 systemd-resolved error NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns

I'm currently testing Ubuntu 20.04.1 (after decades using Fedora from Core 2 to 31), and I have currently issue with local/private DNS resolution.

Getting systematically error messages linked to [this vulnerability](https://github.com/dns-violations/dns-violations/blob/master/2018/DVE-2018-0001.md):

> Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP

Simplified context:

- I have a Synology Router which provides Ethernet network (its @IP address 192.168.56.1)
- it is the one providing DHCP server
- each of my devices (about 10) have a specific DHCP registration, with a specific name

For sake of simplification, let's consider the Device named 'nas'.

Out of the box, my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS refuses to resolve nas, whatever the used command, see end of this question.

After plenty of readings on Stackoverflow, and Forum, I tried, without success:

- install libnss-resolve, which enhance **/etc/nsswitch.conf** file
- change **/etc/resolv.conf** symbolic link from **/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf** to **/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf**
- hack **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** file specifying @IP address of my router as DNS server
- hack **/etc/sysctl.conf** file to define **kernel.domainname** with a specific domain, like defined on my Synology Router (previously there was none, and it was working with Fedora)
- flush the cache `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`

Tests:

```
systemd-resolve nas
```

```
nas: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

---

```
dig nas
```

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> nas
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 65082
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nas.               IN  A

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: mer. juil. 29 15:13:09 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

---

```
dig @192.168.56.1 nas
```

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.56.1 nas
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 34633
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nas.               IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86064   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020072900 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.56.1#53(192.168.56.1)
;; WHEN: mer. juil. 29 15:13:30 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

---

```
nslookup nas
```

> Server:       127.0.0.53 Address: 127.0.0.53#53
>
> ** server can't find nas: SERVFAIL

---

Current contents of my **/etc/resolv.conf** (the default one):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Current contents of my **/etc/nsswitch.conf**:

```
passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

---

Of course, adding @ip/name mapping in **/etc/hosts** works but it is NOT a solution.

Edit: I still have the same issue under Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, with my very new Synology RT2600ac. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: My setup is like yours except 1) I have a search <router supplied default dom> at the end of my (stub) resolv.conf.  2)nslookup,ping, dig name all work for me (this month). Last month, this same setup failed, so is your system fully updated?  I also wondered about missing mdns4 in the nsswitch.conf (like the 18.04 has).  Local names seem to be a moving target, ;^(

Comment: Yes my system is updated to 20.04.1 LTS, and security updates are installed. I tried adding the `search <my router @IP>` without success :/   What do you mean by missing mdns4 in **nsswitch.conf** ?

Comment: See https://github.com/datawire/teleproxy/issues/60  The mdns4_minimal only handles .local  Wrong about 18.04, it's not there now, Don't recall where I saw it, but the link has an example of using both.

Comment: My issue is still not solved ... I put a bounty on it to get a complete working solution. Thanks to everyone trying to solve that ;)

Comment: `dig @192.168.56.1 nas` is not returning the IP address of nas. Fix the DNS on the router so the lookup works, then I have luck with /etc/systemd/resolved.conf configured and the link /etc/resolv.conf pointing to ../run/.../resolv.conf. I run a dnsmasq instance for my local DNS because my router does not do local dns.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, without changing anything on my Router, DNS resolution was perfectly working under Fedora ...

Comment: I just installed a 20.04.1 vm, setup a static ip and dns as 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1. So no local DNS. With Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon running and the same on other hosts, the new machine can run commands with hostname.local. But without a working local DNS I don't see how dns queries would resolve names. So you can `ping hostname.local` or access a web server on the same but cannot do `host hostname` or `host hostname.local`.

Comment: @Guser314 so you recommend installing a dnsmasq server?

Comment: No one for the bounty?

Comment: In lieu of fixing dns on the Synology, then you would need a DNS server for local names and dnsmasq is an easy way to provide that service. I run dnsmasq on a small always on computer and hand it out as the first dns ip address for my network. Though I would debug the Synology more as I found indications it can act as a DNS server.

Comment: Do you have a Synology yourself; do you have any tips how to "fix dns on the Synology"?

Comment: 50 min remaining for this bounty ... Challenge ! ^^

Comment: Hello, I still have the same issue under Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, with my very new Synology RT2600ac. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Is your Synology router setup to provide DNS resolution? Is your Ubuntu host a server or desktop installation? Typically, you need to setup a “search domain” that matches the domain setting in your Synology router. Perhaps the default search domain in Fedora was already set and accurate.

Comment: Yep Synology router is configured to provide DNS resolution (and I can see logged request). Nevertheless, I guess there is an issue with "search domain"; atm it is simply '.'; and I do not have a domain configured on my router anymore. 
I don't know which **local** domain I can use; to be noted that I only would like that when requesting local device/hostname resolution, my router return the corresponding local @ip address, it perfectly knows because it provides them with DHCP server, and "static" reservation. I don't find what is missing to get this single need reached.

Answer (score 1):

This error means the DNS server could not resolve the domain. It generally means that your local dns setup sends queries about local domains (.local, .lan, .home, ...) to remode dns servers.
In my case, I had configured "Domains=" (with my local search domain) in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, but no "DNS=" (leaving this to DHCP), which is wrong. When the dns server is provided by dhcp, the search domain has to be provided the same way.

Comment: So you mean, you fixed your issue, with no more things defined in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: In my opinion, debugging a dns configuration could be made much easier if there was a --verbose or --debug flag to the systemd-resolve (resolvectl) tool.

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately it still doesn't work, I still have `systemd-resolved[1273]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.`

Comment: Some other relevant settings: https://askubuntu.com/a/1179542/935172

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether this is a Server or Desktop installation. Either way, I'll outline how to set a search domain for you. Your original post indicates that you were using Ubuntu 20.04, but you've since upgraded to 22.04.

> **Side note:**
> The following would apply to both 20.04 and 22.04, but the output of
> `resolvectl status` looks a bit different between versions.

With regards to what search domain to use, this is dependent on what's been defined in the DHCP server on your router. It's typically something like *local*, *localdomain*, or *lan*. You can edit as wanted.

I'm using a pfSense router. A domain is entered on the *System/General Setup* page. In my case, the default is *localdomain*, which I've left as configured.

[image]

I'm not familiar with Synology routers, so you'll have to consult the manual on how to define a domain. You've indicated in a comment that you "*do not have a domain configured on my router anymore.*" I suspect this is part of the problem.

To clarify the purpose of a search domain, the manpage for [systemd-resolved.service(8)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html) explains it rather well:

> Queries for the address records (A and AAAA) of single-label
> non-synthesized names are resolved via unicast DNS using
> search domains. For any interface which defines search
> domains, such look-ups are routed to the servers defined for
> that interface, suffixed with each of those search domains.
> When global search domains are defined, such look-ups are
> routed to the global servers. For each search domain, queries
> are performed by suffixing the name with each of the search
> domains in turn.

---

Let's get started...

I see that you've edited `/etc/resolv.conf` in your attempts to solve your problem. So let's reset this file as a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, which is the local caching stub resolver and the default setup.

Run `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` to see what it currently is. On my system, I get the following:

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Dec 31  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

If it's a file or a symlink to something other than `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, then delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

Next, create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

Now let's add a search domain to a network interface for both a Server and Desktop host.

**Server**

Networking is typically configured via *Netplan* and managed by *systemd-networkd* as the backend renderer. Let's see how the current system is setup before making any changes.

On a virtual machine, I have the following *Netplan* YAML config file with an interface setup as DHCP.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-network.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Show the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` before any changes. Note that a search domain is not listed.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

In the following output of `resolvectl status eth0`, I'm only showing one specific link. Substitute `eth0` with your device name. Notice that it doesn't indicate a setting for `DNS Domain`, which is where a search domain would be listed.

```
$ resolvectl status eth0
Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS
                    DNSSEC=no/unsupported         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.10.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
```

Now that we've seen the current state, let's edit your Netplan config file. Substitute the name of your config file in the following command:

```
sudo /etc/netplan/00-network.yaml
```

To add a search domain, edit your config file as follows. In this example, I'm adding *localdomain* as a search domain.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-network.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      nameservers:
        search: [localdomain]
```

Save and exit the file. Then apply the changes:

```
sudo netplan try
```

Restart systemd-resolved:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Then look at the output of `/etc/resolv.conf` and you'll see the search domain has been added.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search localdomain
```

Likewise, `resolvectl status eth0` shows that *localdomain* is listed under `DNS Domain`.

```
$ resolvectl status eth0
Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS
                    DNSSEC=no/unsupported         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.10.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
          DNS Domain: localdomain
```

**Desktop**

With a Desktop installation, networking is typically managed by *Network Manager*. Therefore, we'll use `nm-connection-editor` to open the *Network Connections* editor and add a search domain to an interface.

Before editing a connection, let's look at the current state before adding a new search domain. Enter `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. On my system...

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

Enter `nm-connection-editor` in a terminal. A *Network Connections* window will open. Select your interface that you want to edit, then click the gear icon on the bottom. A new window will open. Select the *IPv4 Settings* tab and enter a search domain under *Additional Search Domains*. In the below image, I'm editing a wifi connection called *Bluwave* and I've entered *localdomain* as an additional search domain.

[image]

Click Save to close this window. Then close the *Network Connections* window.

The effects of this edit can be seen in Network Manager system-connections config files in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. The name of the file for the above connection is `Bluewave.nmconnection`. Yours will be different. Here are the contents before adding *localdomain* as a search domain on my interface. Note that `dns-search` is empty.

```
$ sudo cat Bluwave.nmconnection 
[connection]
id=Bluwave
uuid=e37ca330-8072-4c45-a5f9-e6ac73f3351b
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp9s0
permissions=
timestamp=1691197080

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=04:D5:90:AC:79:F0;04:D5:90:AC:79:F8;04:D5:90:AC:8E:00;04:D5:90:AC:8E:08;
ssid=Bluwave

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

[proxy]
```

After adding the search domain, you'll see the *localdomain* added to `dns-search`:

```
$ sudo cat Bluwave.nmconnection 
[connection]
id=Bluwave
uuid=e37ca330-8072-4c45-a5f9-e6ac73f3351b
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp9s0
permissions=
timestamp=1691197080

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=04:D5:90:AC:79:F0;04:D5:90:AC:79:F8;04:D5:90:AC:8E:00;04:D5:90:AC:8E:08;
ssid=Bluwave

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[ipv4]
dns-search=localdomain
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Anyway, *Network Manager* needs to restart (or a reboot) for this change to take effect. So back in the terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Your new search domain should be in effect. To confirm, look again at `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Notice how the search domain of *localdomain* has been added.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search localdomain
```

This is also shown in the output of `resolvectl status`. In the following output, I'm only showing my specific wifi device. Substitute `wlp9s0` with your device name.

```
$ resolvectl status wlp9s0
Link 3 (wlp9s0)
$ resolvectl status eth0
Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS
                    DNSSEC=no/unsupported         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.10.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      localdomain
```

---

When it's all said and done, you should be able to `ping` your server or run `nslookup` with it's hostname. As an example on my network:

```
$ ping -c 1 office
PING office.localdomain (192.168.10.30) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from OFFICE.localdomain (192.168.10.30): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.385 ms

--- office.localdomain ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.385/0.385/0.385/0.000 ms



$ nslookup office
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   office.localdomain
Address: 192.168.10.30
```