# ubuntu 20.04 freezes with error Server returned error NXDOMAIN

Tags: freeze, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

my ubuntu 20.04 machine has been periodically freezing over the past several weeks. When I hold the power button down and power off the machine and restart, looking at /var/log/syslog, the last entry prior to freezing is as follows:

```
Jan 26 09:31:41 jason-All-Series systemd-resolved[1385]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

I saw [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential), but there was no mention of the machine freezing, and some said the error is best ignored.

Am I correct that my machine freezes as a result of this error?

Comment: What is the machine typically doing when it freezes? Have you confirmed that there aren't temperature or storage reliability issues that might be causing the issue?

Comment: just typical internet browsing, not doing anything particularly unusual. I did have a period prior to this where the machine would freeze and I would see temp related errors in syslog, but I put a new cpu cooler in the machine and those errors did not continue. My troubleshooting consists mainly of looking at the syslog entries at the time of the freeze...are there other places I should be looking?